# Trying to search a list of words for a signgular letter and then retun all words containing that letter in shceme

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to write a function called words-containing. when given a (possibly empty) list of words (as a list of lists of chars) and a char which yields only the words containing that char.

This is my attempt:

```
(define (words-containing all-words char )
  (cond
  [(empty? all-words) ()]
  [( equal? (car all-words) char) (words-containing (cdr all-words) char)]
  [else(words-containing (cdr all-words) char)]))
```

This is what the outcome should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2xDt.png)

Comment: Sorry that is an old code where i tried to get the total number of words containing the letter rather than the whole word, I have ameneded my error

Comment: If you got that function working, this is the same but with lists instead of numbers and `cons` instead of `+`. (Also, there's a library function `filter` that can do the work for you.)